# Constructor not defined: [pagereference].<Constructor>(String)

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public PageReference requestCode(){
        String endpoint='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';
        endpoint=endpoint+'?response_type=code&client_id='+clientId;
        endpoint=endpoint+'&redirect_uri='+redirectUri;
        PageReference p=new PageReference(endpoint);
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh, welcome to SFSE. Your question does not contain any details around your issue, your efforts around resolution and what assistance do you need here. Your chances of getting a response increases if you provide more details, so that folks out here can help you in a better way. Take a moment to go through [How to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide details in your question, so that others can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PageReference` was the Salesforce class, the message would include this:

```
[System.PageReference]
```

rather than:

```
[pagereference]
```

so it is likely that you have a local `pagereference` class that is hiding the Salesforce class. Generally best not to use the same names to avoid this problem, but a quick workaround is to qualify the class name:

```
System.PageReference p = new System.PageReference(endpoint);
```